# CFML: Authenticated user being matched on third party forum plugin so he is 'logged in'

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, forum

Alright here is the situation.

I have been tasked at my work to integrate a coldfusion forum (Galleon) into the existing CRM that are using for the merchants.

The issue is, the original CRM itself has its own login and a 'user' table in the database. Galleon uses its own login page and 'user' file..

My partner and I on this are racking our brains trying to figure out this (admittedly simple) problem. We thought about the possibility of defining a global variable, like a session, and once triggered by the primary login for the CRM it would bypass the Galleon login.

But this doesn't solve the problem of telling Galleon who the user is so he can post..

I'm thinking one of the ways to solve this issue is to insert the entirety of the original CRM user file into the Galleon user file. That way it has a list of identical user\passes.

Any ideas guys?

Breakdown:

User logins in at CRM splash page----->Brought to CRM index.cfm\main panel. User can then click on "CRM FORUM!" and instead of being re prompted for a user\pass Galleon knows who he is and allows him to make threads and post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are definitely a number of ways to skin the cat on this. I downloaded the Galleon 2 forum code to take a peek at the user.cfc

You could modify the query in this function to pull the fields it requires from your CMS:

```
<cffunction name="getUser" access="public" returnType="struct" output="false" hint="Returns a user.">

<cfquery name="qGetUser" datasource="#variables.dsn#">      
SELECT
    [cmsusertable].cmsid as ID,
    [cmsusertable].cmsuser as username, 
    [cmsusertable].cmspassword as password,
    [cmsusertable].cmsemail as emailaddress,
    [cmsusertable].createDate as datecreated,
    [cmsusertable].cmsactive as confirmed, 
    [cmsusertable].cmssignature as signature,
    [cmsusertable].cmsavatar as avatar
FROM
    [cmsusertable]users
WHERE 
    [cmsusertable].username = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.username#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="50">
</cfquery>
```

Remember that you must return the fields from the query as Galleon expects them, so use the 'as' statement to rename your CMS database fields to what Galleon expects. Now some of these extraneous fields you might not have in your CMS table such as Signature / Avatar. If you can extend your CMS table and user routines to accommodate these fields, that might be good. Or you could modify the profile routines in Galleon to only update the Signature/Avatar instead of the whole profile. If you do use the Galleon tables to store this information, remember to add a join to include these fields where requested to reunify the user data.

You'll also have to modify the joins in about 4 files (user.cfc, conference.cfc, message.cfc, thread.cfc) in the project to join with your CMS user table instead.

Lastly, you'll have to modify the the login.cfm to simply attempt to set the session.user struct using the information in the CMS user session and failing that, redirect the user back to the CMS login page.

Overall I don't think it would be too difficult. I'm sure there's stuff I missed but perhaps that would get you going.

Answer (score 0):

What you described is exactly how many sites work, regardless of the mechanism you use to authenticate (i.e.; OAuth, Twitter, etc.) You use the external service for authentication, and you get back a token of some kind from that external service that says "This person really is authenticated." It's up to your code -- Galleon in this case -- to say "This person is authenticated, but they don't have an account in our system. Let's make one." This usually requires you to go back to the external service to get a name, email address, etc.

You will most likely have to do some additional work in your external service to allow for updates of customer information in Galleon. If, for example, someone changes their email address, there's more than likely an email address in Galleon which should also be updated. This can get complicated, but is a necessity from the customer's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to sync up your Galleon forum user table with your CRM, then keep them in sync as you add/remove/update CRM users.

The key to doing this is by utilizing the Galleon business layer API-- a.k.a. the public methods in the Galleon CFCs. This will keep you from having to modify ANY of Galleon's code, which I would highly recommend if you'd like to easily install Galleon updates. (By the way, you should keep your 3rd party codebase up to date, since open source projects are popular targets for hackers-- especially forums.)

To sync up your existing users, you'll want to write a script that iterates through your current CRM's users and calls Galleon's User.addUser() method for each user, using the same user/pass combo as your CRM (or maybe use hashes of them). Be sure to break on any Galleon errors/failures so you don't miss any users.

To keep Galleon in sync with your CRM, add calls to Galleon's CFCs as needed. For instance, call User.deleteUser() when you delete a user from your CRM.

For authentication, you'll use User.authenticate(), passing in the same user/pass combo as your CRM.

Utilizing the business-layer API of 3rd-party libraries is a much better long-term solution than trying to modify them to suit your needs.